# Showing a set is (or is not) bounded and totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the metric given by $d(x,y)=8$ if $x≠y$ and $d(x,x)=0$. Let $A=\mathbb Z=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots\}$.

To show that $A$ is bounded, I was told that I should choose $1/2∈X$ and $d(1/2,x)=8$ for all $x∈A$, hence showing that $A$ is bounded. I thought to show something was bounded we needed to create one single open ball around the whole set. Here, the set is infinite which I would assume would require an infinite amount of balls.

To show that $A$ is totally bounded, I was told that I should always pick half of the distance given of the metric as my $\varepsilon$ and show that there a single point in each open ball (and if not then it is not totally bounded. Is this correct? Then is it safe to assume that for any infinite set, no matter the metric, it will always not be totally bounded because I won't be able to have a finite number of open balls to cover the set?

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition.** A subset $A \subseteq X$ of a metric space $X$ is bounded iff there exists $r > 0$ and $x_0 \in X$ such that the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ is a superset of $A$.

You don't need infinitely many balls. As you can see from the definition, the requirement of boundedness has nothing to do with the cardinality of the set you're trying to show is bounded. One ball indeed suffices: the open ball of radius $r=9$ around the point $x_0=1/2$ encloses the whole set $A$.

> **Definition.** A subset $A \subseteq X$ of a metric space $X$ is totally bounded iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a finite collection of open balls of radius $\varepsilon$ whose union contains $A$.

If $\varepsilon \geq 8$, you're done: the collection of balls required in the definition can be taken to contain even just one ball, centered at whatever $x_0 \in X$. But if say $\varepsilon = 7<8$, then the open ball centered at $x_0 \in X$ with radius $\varepsilon$ only contains the point $x_0$. Since $A$ is infinite, you'd need infinitely many such balls to cover $A$. So $A$ is *not* totally bounded.

However, as you can see, this conclusion is heavily dependent on the fact that the metric is *discrete* (it can only attain one of the two values $0$ and $8$). Once we equip $X$ with a non-discrete metric, we can find infinite subsets that are totally bounded. Take for example $\mathbb R$ with the standard metric, and $A$ to be the image of the sequence $\{1/n\}$. Then $A$ is totally bounded, since for every choice of $\varepsilon$ the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $0$ will contain an infinite amount of points of $A$, leaving out finitely many points that can be taken care of by finitely many other balls (if necessary).

Comment: I somewhat see what you are saying. Is it safe to say that, because my metric was smaller than the set A, that all that matters was for me to find a single open ball at a point within the metric that overlapped with the set? Meaning since {-8,...8} is the part of the integers that overlaps with the metric, that is all I care to cover? I guess that is sort of confusing because I know the goal is to cover the whole set and here we are only covering up everything in between (not including) -8.5 and 8.5. @giobrach

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the discrete metric in your problem with the standard metric on $X$. At any point $x\in X$, if $r \geq 8$ the open ball of radius $r$ coincides with the whole $X$, while if $r<8$ it coincides with the singleton $\{x\}$. There is no in-between option; thus, in this discrete metric space, there is no way to partially cover $A$ in the way you're suggesting. (Also "metric" technically only refers to the map $d$, not the balls invoked in the definition of (total) boundedness, so you shouldn't confuse the two terms.)

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Could a possible answer to the boundedness section have been 1∈ and an open ball of radius 8 have worked? I am trying to think of steps to take when finding out whether something is bounded or not as well as totally bounded or not. (somewhat like, check if the metric is blank if so then do the following) but I am having trouble seeing the steps for boundedness here. @giobrach

Comment: That choice would have worked, as that ball coincides with $X$: see my previous comment.

Comment: The best way to check whether something is (totally) bounded is to go back to the definition of these two properties and work from there, as I've done in my answer. It helps to try to understand what form the open balls take in the specific metric space you're working with. It also helps to try to understand the shape of the set $A$, if it is a subset of a known set $X$ like here; in that case, maybe consider drawing it on a piece of paper.